# Несколько условий для Mysql запроса

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица, в ней есть колонка meta_key и meta_value
Вот запр

```
SELECT post_id 
FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE (meta_key="_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_2_fieldID_7_numInSet_0") 
  AND (meta_value="radiobutton_num_3") 
  AND (meta_key="_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_2_fieldID_8_numInSet_0") 
  AND (meta_value="radiobutton_num_2")
```

надо первую часть(meta_key и meta_value) типо как поместить в скобки.
Этот запрос возвращает пустую строку, хотя есть такие поля которые и

```
   ((meta_key="_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_2_fieldID_7_numInSet_0") 
AND (meta_value="radiobutton_num_3"))
```

и

```
   ((meta_key="_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_2_fieldID_8_numInSet_0") 
AND (meta_value="radiobutton_num_2"))
```

Это код фильтра записей.
Очень спасибо за помощь

Comment: Вы пытаетесь найти ОДНУ запись, в которой поле meta_key ОДНОВРЕМЕННО имеет два разных значения (и meta_value - тоже). Ясен пень ничего не получается. Почитайте теорию по термину "реляционное деление", посмотрите примеры запросов...

Comment: meta_key не ключевое поле

Comment: Да похрен ключ. Ну не может ОДНО поле ОДНОЙ записи быть одновременно равно и 2, и 3, только что-то одно.

Comment: а да, мне не принципиально одну, как раз я ищу несколько записей

Comment: Ну тогда `WHERE (meta_key=1 AND meta_value=2) OR (meta_key=3 AND meta_value=4)`. Или лучше `WHERE (metakey, meta_value) IN ( (1, 2), (3, 4) )`.